# Is there another way of solving this differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$y'+y\tan x=\dfrac{1}{\cos x}$

I found the integrating factor to be $e^{-\ln\cos x}$, but then I get into having to integrate $\dfrac{-\ln\cos x}{\cos x}$ , which seems to be quite a mess. Is there any other way of solving that equation (or an easy way to integrate)?

Comment: You can simplify a lot $e^{-lncosx}$

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: multiply by $\cos x$

Comment: hint: you will get $y_h=C\cos(x)$

Comment: I think he means $e^{-\ln\cos(x)} = e^{\ln(1/\cos(x))} = 1/\cos(x)$

Comment: $e^{log(a)}=a$ ...

Answer (score 3):

$1 = (\cos x) y^\prime + y \sin x = (y\cos x)^\prime$ so $y\cos x = x + C$

EDIT: i made a mistake as pointed out by sas.

the homogeneous solution is $\cos x \dfrac{dy}{dx}  + y \sin x = 0$ which can be rewritten as $\dfrac{dy}{y} = \dfrac{d\cos x}{\cos x}$  so $y = A\cos x$ we will try variation of parameters, i.e. assume a solution of the form 
$y = A\cos x, \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \cos x \dfrac{dA}{dx} - A \sin x$ putting this in the nonhomogeneous equation you get $$1 = \cos x(\cos x \dfrac{dA}{dx} - A \sin x)+A \sin \cos x = \cos^2 x \dfrac{dA}{dx}$$ therefore $A = \tan x + C, y = \cos x(\tan x + C) = \sin x +  C \cos x $

the solution to the problem is $$y = \sin x +  C \cos x \text{ where $C$ is a constant } $$

Comment: It is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $\cos x$: $$y'\cos x + y\sin x=1$$
That means $$y'\cos x + y\sin x - \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x = 0$$
or $$(y'-\cos x)\cos x + (y-\sin x)\sin x=0$$
$$(y-\sin x)'\cos x - (y-\sin x)(\cos x)'=0$$
as $\cos x \neq 0$
$$\dfrac{(y-\sin x)'\cos x - (y-\sin x)(\cos x)'}{\cos^2 x}=\left(\dfrac{y-\sin x}{\cos x}\right)'=0$$
$$y=C\cos x + \sin x$$

Answer (score 0):

Alot of nice methods above. Though, plodding on with the original OP method and Claude Leibovici insight you get
$$
y\mathrm{e}^{-\ln \cos x} = \int \sec x \mathrm{e}^{-\ln \cos x} dx = \int \sec x \frac{1}{\cos x}dx = \int \sec ^2 x dx = \tan x + C
$$
thus
$$
y\frac{1}{\cos x} = \tan x + C \implies y = \sin x + C\cos x
$$